# *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString()) does not return the string of node.js addon argument

Tags: c++, c, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I've found that *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString()) returns the proper string on node 0.8.2 32-bit and does not return the proper string on node 0.8.8 64-bit.

does anybody understand why?

My node.js addon looks like this:

```
#define BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION
#include <node.h>

#define MAX_OUTPUT_BUF  80
extern "C" char *do_sqlsig(char *in);

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> Sqlsig(const Arguments& args) {
 HandleScope scope;
 char *c_arg, *ret;

 if (args.Length() < 1) {
   ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Wrong number of arguments")));
   return scope.Close(Undefined());
 }

 c_arg = *v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString());

 ret = c_arg; //do_sqlsig(c_arg);

 return scope.Close(String::New(ret));
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("sqlsig"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Sqlsig)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(sqlsig, Init)
```

As you can see I'm writing a wrapper for the C function, do_sqlsig. I know C very well and know very little about C++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string that the pointer returned from `*v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString());` is point at is destroyed at the end of this line (when `Utf8Value` is destroyed). You create and destroy a `Utf8Value` object in one line. It is undefined behavior when dereferencing a dangling pointer, and why you are seeing different results on different versions.

Break it up into two lines and the string will be valid as long as your `Utf8Value` object is in scope.

```
v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[0]->ToString());
c_arg = *str;
```